# Installing Numpy on Fedora 19 with pip

Tags: python, numpy, pip, fedora

I tried to install Python 2.7 `Numpy` module on Fedora 19 using `pip`:

```
sudo pip install numpy
```

But I have the following error:

```
"Cannot compile 'Python.h'. Perhaps you need to "\

SystemError: Cannot compile 'Python.h'. Perhaps you need to install python-dev|python-devel.

----------------------------------------
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-root/numpy
Storing complete log in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

How can I fix that?

Thanks.

Comment: Just because you didn't say, have you tried installing python-devel with yum? 'yum install python-devel'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sudo yum install python-devel
```

And then it shall work flawlessly.

Answer (score 3):

The development version of python needs to be installed:

```
yum install python-devel
```