# Installing NumPy on Fedora 24 with pip

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, pip

My question is perhaps similar to [Installing Numpy on Fedora 19 with pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19050386/installing-numpy-on-fedora-19-with-pip).

I would like to install NumPy with `pip` on (a freshly installed) Fedora 24.

Fedora already has `pip` (via the command pip3). When I write `pip3 install numpy`, pip downloads a zip (with the source code inside) and tries to compile (build a local wheel). But I do not have Python headers so it can't compile. I guess that if I install python3-devel pip will manage to compile NumPy as I already have GCC (but no linear algebra library).

But what I want to do is to install NumPy from a wheel only. Normally if a wheel is available on PyPI, then pip will download the corresponding wheel file. It is so on other distributions: Arch, Ubuntu. I installed the package `python3-wheel` also, but it didn't have any effect.

Can somebody make the situation clearer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to upgrade your pip.

I've just tried to install *numpy* on fresh fedora container and pip tried to download sources and compile them, and failed because of python3-devel missing.

But I updated pip with `pip3 install --upgrade pip` and afterwards `pip3 install numpy` downloaded `numpy-1.11.1-cp35-cp35m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl` file and isnstaled it without issues.